# How to display data of Resultset having duplicate values

Tags: java, sql, el

I have a result set from select query:

```
select user_name,permission_description from users
inner join user_permission 
on user_permission.user_id = users.user_id
inner join permissions
on permissions.permission_id = user_permission.permission_id
```

Result:

```
user_name     permission
user1         view
user1         add
user2         view
user2         add
user2         edit
```

I have POJOs of `User` and `Permission`.
I am confused on how to store the values from result set and store them in pojo, so that i can display it on JSP page.

Should I use `List` or `Map`, and how?

Comment: User class should have Set<Permission> to reflect user's permissions

Answer (score 0):

You can use list of pojo here..iterate through result set, make new object and store it in list

here is some code..

```
// Fetch each row from the result set
while (rs.next()) {
  String i = rs.getString("user_name");
  String str = rs.getString("permission");

  //Assuming you have a user object
  User user = new User(i, str);

  ll.add(user);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like each user can have multiple permissions. So model like that. Have a class called `User` that has a property `Permissions` which is a `List<Permission>` where `Permission` just contains the names. You could just use a `String` for `Permission` but perhaps you requirements need something more complex.

Comment: Hi Sean,yes you got it right.The POJO User has a get property which is List<Permission>.Permission contains only names.After executing the select query, i am getting result as shown in above table.In Jsp, i want to show that the User1 has add, view permissions. Please suggest me how to achieve it.

Comment: before displaying your POJO, make sure to fill all its permissions. so when you are looping on the records, store the users in a map. then everytime you have a user, get the object from the map (and create it if it does not exist) and add the current permission to its permissions.

Comment: Hi Sean, I could have used only String, but the requirement is something like that.